# Reduce three dimensional array to a vector of significant numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, histogram

Hi I have a three dimensional array in Matlab, something like <10 x 10 x 100> and I would like to reduce this array to a vector of significant numbers. For example I would like to take each matrix(picture) split it in half by columns, compute sum(left)-sum(right) and return this <1 x 100> vector back. Unfortunately I cannot figure out or find out how to do that. Is it possible? And how could I achieve it?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner, given a matrix `A`:

```
result = -squeeze(diff(sum(reshape(A, [50 2 100]), 1), 1, 2)).';
```

### How it works:

First, [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the data into a 50-by-2-by-100 matrix where values from the left half of each matrix are in column 1 and values from the right half of each matrix are in column 2. Then apply [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) down each column to get a 1-by-2-by-100 matrix. You can then take the difference between the columns with [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), although this subtracts the left column from the right, so you have to add a minus to negate the result. The resulting 1-by-1-by-100 matrix can be collapsed to a 100-by-1 column vector with [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html), and this can be [transposed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) into a row vector. Alternatively, you can use another `reshape` instead of the `squeeze` and transpose:

```
result = -reshape(diff(sum(reshape(A, [50 2 100]), 1), 1, 2), [1 100]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)